# When do we use "be careful about"?

Tags: prepositions

Most of the time we use be careful 'with'/ 'of'. but i realized there are times people use be careful about. What is the grammar rule behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reality here is that this is more about style than any hard rule. I would argue that 'about' as a preposition after 'be careful', whilst not incorrect, is certainly unusual. Most definitely it should be used when the subjective noun implies a place.

I would also contend that "about" implies a more general or ordinary subject. Whereas 'of' and 'with' are more specific.

> General usage: "Be careful about town, there are thieves on every corner."
>
> Specific usage: "Be careful of thieves, they are everywhere in town."
>
> Specific usage: "Be careful with your money, thieves are everywhere in town."

https://www.englishforums.com/English/WhenPrepositionsAboutOn/lvqxw/post.htm

Comment: Is this grammatical?: Some of the messages also remind people to be careful "with" the water they drink every day.

Comment: How about "be careful about what you say"?